# Await function not working with jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, promise, event-handling

I have a SweetAlert2 popup that's verifying images uploaded by users. After the user decides I need to continue/stop the main function.

But it just ignores the .then function appended to Swal.
So if the img have good resolution, it **returns true**. And else it just **returns false**. Even if the popup shows. It already ran the rest of the main function code.
Img verify function:

```
function verifyimage(imgurl) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src = imgurl;
    $(tmpImg).on("load", function () {
      var orgWidth = tmpImg.width; //w
      var orgHeight = tmpImg.height; //h
      if (orgHeight <= 720 || orgWidth <= 1500) {
        Swal.fire({
          position: "center",
          icon: "error",
          title: `title`,
          showConfirmButton: true,
          showCancelButton: true
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            resolve(true); //img ok
          } else {
            resolve(false); //dont upload
          }
        });
      } else {
        resolve(true); //upload, good resolution
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Main function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#upload-it", async function() {
  var valueimg = geturl();
  var imgvefify = await verifyimage(valueimg);
  if (!imgvefify) {
    console.log("nope, invalid img");
    return false;
  }
//upload to server etc..
});
```

Comment: Why you are not using promise rejection in case of error? resolve(false) needs to be replaced with reject

Comment: @YousafHassan It's not an error when the user clicks on the "Cancel" button. He's using it as a boolean, so `resolve(false)` is correct.

Comment: Why don't you declare `verifyimage` as an async function, then use `return await swal(...)`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163281/how-to-have-sweetalert-return-true-false-for-confirm-without-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've phrased this question as if SweetAlert2 is not respecting your `then`, but I think it's actually the case that jQuery is not waiting for or respecting your `return false`; you're issuing it in an `async function` and jQuery simply doesn't know how to await Promises in event handlers.

Your function passed to `on` returns a Promise, because all `async` functions return a Promise in all cases. It seems like you want the `return false` to cancel the default behavior of the `#upload-it` button that presumably submits a form, but JavaScript event handlers don't understand when event handlers return Promises, and [jQuery doesn't either](https://api.jquery.com/on/). This makes it impossible to use `return false` to cancel the default behavior in an `async function` event handler.

Instead, make sure to [immediately prevent the default behavior and stop propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59811412/1426891) before awaiting anything, which you can do [by calling methods on the event object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30473581/1426891). Having prevented the default behavior, you won't be able to "continue" it once the `async function` completes, but you can still [programmatically submit the form](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```js
$(document).on("click", "#upload-it", async function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  // validate the form
  // upload to server etc..
});
```